# Pdf calculation of two random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

If $X = aY + b$, both $X$ and $Y$ are random variable. The pdf of $Y$ is given, can anybody please tell how to find pdf of $X$ ?

Comment: if pdf of Y is P(y) = F(x), then the pdf should be F(x-b/a) but in answer it says 1/aF(x-b/a) I dont know from where 1/a comes ?

Comment: Probability that $X=x$ is the probability that $aY+b=x$, which is the probability that $aY=x-b$, which (if $a\ne 0$) is the probability that $Y=\frac{x-b}{a}$.

Answer (score 1):

You calculate questions like these always via the cumulative distribution function, because $P(Y=y) = 0$ for all $y$. Thus if $a>0$:
$$
F_Y(y) = P(Y\le y) = P(aX+b\le y) = P(X\le\frac{y-b}{a}) = F_X(\frac{y-b}{a}).
$$
Thus
$$
f_Y(y) = \frac{d}{dy}F_Y(y) = \frac{d}{dy}F_X(\frac{y-b}{a}) = f_X(\frac{y-b}{a})\frac{1}{a}.
$$
The case $a<0$ works the some and the case $a=0$ is quite straight forward.

Comment: What you are saying about $F$ demands that $a>0$. Also $<$ should be replaced by $\le$

Comment: You're right. If $a<0$, then the inequality sign is reversed.